# Inputing lines to the beginning and end of a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to send lines to the beginning and ending of a file called `testPrint.txt`. The lines I need to send are stored in `testValues.txt`. To do this, I'll need a third file to write all of this to, `tempFile.txt`.

1. I need to write the lines from `testValues.txt` to to `tempFile.txt`.
2. Append the data from `testPrint.txt` to `tempFile.txt`.
3. Next, append the lines from `testVaules.txt` to `tempFile.txt`.
4. Finally, Copy the contents from `tempFile.txt` and overwrite the data on `testPrint.txt` to contain my `testValues.txt` at the beginning and end of the file.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Yes it is possible, and you just answer yourself on how to do it... What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, that's possible, although I don't see why you need the temporary file. Simply hold the data in memory.

1. open `testValues.txt` and `testPrint.txt` in read-only mode (`handle = open(..., 'r')`)
2. read the data with `content = handle.read()`
3. close the files with `handle.close()`
4. open `test.Print.txt` in write mode (`handle = open(..., 'w')`)
5. write the content you want in the order you want and close.

(Instead of explicit `close` you might want to use `open` as contextmanager:

```
with open('testValues.txt', 'r') as testValuesFile:
    testValues = testValuesFile.read()
```

)

Comment: This is a great idea, yet will this ensure that everything is written over? I've come into contact at times where some of the data isn't always written over.

Comment: In the moment you `open('testPrint.txt', 'w')` the file is truncated, thus completely empty and the former contents will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I need to write the lines from `testValues.txt` to to `tempFile.txt`.

```
open('tempFile.txt', 'w').write(open('testValues.txt').read())
```

Append the data from `testPrint.txt` to `tempFile.txt`.

```
open('tempFile.txt', 'a').write(open('testPrint.txt').read())
```

Next, append the lines from `testVaules.txt` to `tempFile.txt`.

```
open('tempFile.txt', 'a').write(open('testVaules.txt').read())
```

Finally, Copy the contents from `tempFile.txt` and overwrite the data on `testPrint.txt` to contain my `testValues.txt` at the beginning and end of the file.

```
open('testPrint.txt', 'w').write(open('tempFile.txt').read())
```

---

Another option:

```
tv = open('testVaules.txt').read()
open('testPrint.txt', 'w').write(tv + open('testPrint.txt').read() + tv)
```

Comment: `open('...', 'w').write(...)` might not properly close the file.

Answer (score 0):

To write to the end of a file:

```
  with open('file.txt', 'a') as outfile:
      outfile.write(row)
```

To write to the beginning:

```
  data = []
  with open('file.txt', 'r') as infile:
      for row in infile:
          data.append(row)
  with open('file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      for row in data:
          outfile.write(row)
```